# problem with my code a variable that cannot be used with < o >

Tags: python, string, variables, while-loop, typeerror

```
power=input("How much power would you like to have?(power goes from 1 to a 100)")
while power > 100 or power < 0:
    if power < 100 or power > 0:
        break
    else:
        power=input("How much power would you like to have?")
```

when i try to run this part of a code it keeps showing an error message that looks like:     while puissance > 100 or puissance < 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `input` returns a string, so you need to have `power = int(input("blah"))`

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function returns a string (`str`).  To convert it to an `int` you need to use the `int` function:

```
power = int(input("How much power would you like to have?(power goes from 1 to a 100)"))
```

Note that `int()` will raise a `ValueError` if the string the user inputs isn't one that can be interpreted as an integer.

If you want to repeatedly prompt the user until they provide a valid value, use a loop with a `try`/`except`:

```
while True:
    try:
        power = int(input(
            "How much power would you like to have? (power goes from 1 to 100)"
        ))                        # raises ValueError if not an int
        assert 1 <= power <= 100  # raises AssertionError if not in range
    except (AssertionError, ValueError):
        continue  # prompt again
    else:
        break     # continue on with this power value
```